# How to create the right side of the Photoshop CC 2015 Splash graphic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

[image: This effect]

I know it can  be done using Wind filter. I have tried. But it's not giving the fusion of multiple colors like this. I am unable the get feel of multiple layers of multiple colors.

Comment: If you want to do this using wind, you'll probably have to do it to each color as its own layer and then blend them together.  You could also try using the smudge tool with the hardness turned up.  Doing it by hand might take a while though.

Comment: How can I get the wavy shape of the edge? Using wind filter is giving the straight edge. Moreover doing with different layer for each color is not giving the fusion of colors.

Comment: Wavy shape of the color's edge or the staggered lengths of the wind lines?  I also said "probably" haha I haven't actually tried this myself yet (I'm at work) but that's just an idea that I thought might work.

Comment: I just tried a little and think Wind is definitely used. I'll try more tonight because I do like this image (its the PS 2015 Splash Screen). It would probably help to create brushes with Wind applied to expedite the process.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Photoshop CC 2015 Splash]

Alright so first off since I recognize it I thought I'd attach the full image. It really is nice, except the text - don't know what they were thinking with the cheesy text stuff.

I'm pretty sure you're on the right track with the Wind Filter.

Here's my attempt which I think is getting pretty close to the desired effect:

[Starter Image via Unsplash.com](https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1414775838024-666765beb5d9) I used to make this:

[image: Final Mock]

To make it I started with some brushes, they may have used those smokey / liquid brushes from the right side, it would make the most sense. I used some [free Water Color brushes](http://www.brusheezy.com/free/watercolors).

I set my brush Opacity to 83% and then used a variety of the Watercolor brushes in different shades of blue and purple to get something like this:

[image: Water Colored Side]

Then I used Filter > Stylize > Wind set to `Stagger` -- but as you can see in the history panel, I did it a few times:

[image: Wind Filter]

Then I just rotated it and masked out to get the final image. Obviously this is very quick. More refinement, more layers, more colors and really tying it together with the starter image will all help the effect. But hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I also tried using ink brush still not satisfied. But I liked your attempt. I just contacted the Alberto Seveso, asked for help. Hope he will reply soon.

Comment: `Wind` has more to work with, if the edge is blurred.